# rails3 has_and_belongs_to_many customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Book `has_and_belongs_to_many` Students
Student `has_and_belongs_to_many` Books

In BooksStudents model I want to add "status" field to store if it is rented, bought ..etc. and be able to select for example `@student.books.rented` or `@student.books.where(:books_students=>{:status=>2})`

Can I do that with HABTM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK no, you will need a has_many :through setup..

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books_students  
  has_many :students, :through => :books_students
end

class BooksStudent  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book  
  belongs_to :student 
end 

classStudent  < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :books_students  
  has_many :books, :through => :books_students  
end
```

so you can do something like `@student.books` or `@student.student_books.where(:status =>2)`

Comment: I though there could be a way to do it :S anyways I already started implementing it using `has_many :through`. Thanks